# Execute .exe with php

Tags: php, exec, exe

I'm currently working on a localhost WAMP Server and I would like to execute an .exe directly from my browser (to control AIMP player with command lines)
I've been trying all the PHP functions to do that, but none of them executes the .exe file.

With exec(), I can call "java -jar" or launch a .bat, but every attempt for a .exe file fails (even if I call in PHP a java application that launches the .exe itself).

Extra informations :
Safe mode disabled
PHP 5.3.13
Apache 2.2.22

Do you have any idea for my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: The executable file can only be called if it A) resides in the same path as your script, or B) is included as part of your windows PATH variable. `shell_exec('some_file.exe');`

Comment: In what way does it fail?  What is the line of code you're using to call it?  Is there an error message or something in the PHP logs?

Comment: Ohgodwhy : I've tried to copy-paste my program into my PHP's script folder or editing my Windows's path variable, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: David : it doesn't give any error. The command just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing simple function to make background `exec()` directly from browser and set up some output - which could probably show you error. So:

```
function background_exec($command)
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen('start /B ' . $command, 'r'));
    }
    else {
        exec($command . ' 2>&1 > /dev/null &');
    }
}
```

This stuff, as you see, will work both under **win** and **nix**. And calling it for **WAMP** under **win** would be:

```
$command = 'C:\path_to_your_directory\program.exe > C:\path_to_your_directory\logfile.log';
background_exec($command);
```

This worked fine for me, although, I've never experienced problem with running `.exe` files this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, `background_exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\AIMP3\AIMP3.exe" /STOP');` still doesn't do anything. And the redirection to a log file just create an empty file.

Comment: Hmm... You probably tried to start it directly via command line - does it work? If yes, problem is that PHP exec functions on your WAMP just have no idea how to handle .exe extension.

Answer (score -1):

I finally chose to use **websockets** to solve my problem (with Ratchet). Like this, I can invoke my script from my browser passing the arguments I need to the executable file.

PHP in CLI doesn't seem to have any problem  with exec() on .exe files.